# LAST_INSERT_ID without AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have following table, which does have an UUID as primary key, which also acts as foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE `xxx` (
    `guid` char(36) NOT NULL,
    ....
    PRIMARY KEY (`guid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=REDUNDANT ;

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_xxx
  BEFORE INSERT ON xxx
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.guid = uuid();
```

Every time when I insert a new dataset, I need to know which UUID was generated, so I can use this UUID for references. Alas, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` does not work.

```
INSERT INTO `xxx`(...) VALUES (...);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I also tried to modify the trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_xxx
  BEFORE INSERT ON xxx
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.guid = LAST_INSERT_ID(uuid());
```

But it doesn't help either, and [other people have the same problem](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,72236,72240#msg-72240).

A few solutions I can think of, but I don't like them very much ...

**Solution A:**

Generate the UUID by the application which writes the data. Not a good solution, because:

1. it is hard to generate a **real** UUID (which fulfils all criteria of RFC 4122) in PHP.
2. Also, I want to ensure (directly in the DBMS) that people get an unique UUID.
3. With the trigger, I cannot use a custom UUID in the INSERT statement

**Solution B:**

- Add a INT primary key and let GUID be UNIQUE only.
- After inserting, receive the INT primary key with LAST_INSERT_ID
- Run a SELECT statement, which searches the GUID for the given INT primary key.

Since I want to insert a lot of datasets in short time, having a SELECT after each INSERT would make the progress much slower, since the amount of queries doubles.

*Is there an acceptable solution C?*

Comment: option C: a stored procedure?

Comment: Generate the UUID in your app code, it is standard enough. Autoincrement has to be generated by the DB, but that does not hold for UUID. If you have no library to generate it, then just run `SELECT UUID()` before, it will give you one. Last_insert_id() would net be known in before-insert trigger anyway afaik and there is no reason to use the trigger. The uniquenes of the UUID is very probable and the minimal chance of it being duplicate is guarded against by the primary key.

Comment: I agree with the option C of @ypercube 's comment.

Comment: @ypercube How would this stored procedure look like? I never worked with stored procedures before.

Answer (score 1):

What are the 'requirements' of your UUID?  Why isn't an `AUTO_INCREMENT` sufficient?  I believe the use (in C) of mysql_insert_id() does *not* incur an extra round-trip to the server, but rather provides the value from the previous `INSERT`.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-insert-id.html .

If that does not suffice, consider

```
INSERT ... VALUES (..., @uuid = UUID(), ...);
SELECT @uuid; -- or simply use @uuid in whatever needs it next.
```

A note about UUIDs -- They are very "random".  That is, for tables/indexes too large to be cached, they incur a lot of I/O.  More discussion in [*my uuid blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid).

Comment: Is there any document about "mysql_insert_id() does not incur an extra round-trip to the server"? Does this implies that INSERT query result contains the AUTO_INCREMENT value?

Comment: Don't know if there is a document.  Yes, the last_insert_id comes back with the ACK for the `INSERT`.  Are you reaching across a WAN?  (Otherwise, it should not matter.)

Comment: I am not worry about security. I just cannot verify it by tcpdump or other network sniffer, i.e., I cannot see the AUTO_INCREMENT value in response.

Comment: Would you care to share the tcpdump output?

Comment: Did the tcpdump show the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` go across the wire?